# Add list containing dates to PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a list of dates that I would like to add to a Spark dataframe with StructType = StringType. However, the final df below only contains null values.

#Step 1: Create data-range and put into list

```
start_date = '2020-05-01'
end_date = '2020-05-10'

my_dates = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date).tolist()
```

#Step 2: Add list to Spark Df

```
cSchema = StructType([StructField("date", ArrayType(StringType()))])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(my_dates,schema,cSchema)
```

Comment: Use spark.createDataFrame without any schema then convert to string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like:

```
start_date = '2020-05-01'
end_date = '2020-05-10'

my_dates = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date).tolist()

new_df = spark.createDataFrame([(value,) for value in mydates], ['date'])
new_df.show()
```